# What is a "kitchen sink approach"?

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

What does "*kitchen sink approach*" mean in this context?

> Where some startups focus on the minimum viable product, (name of startup) **has gone for a kitchen sink approach** that approximates the functionality you might expect in more mature offerings. (name of product) can even be the platform that runs your application, if that’s what you need.

[Full article](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/11/17/3978)

Does "*kitchen sink approach*" mean providing a lot of features?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Kitchen sink approach* is an allusion to the expression *[everything but the kitchen sink](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kitchen+sink)*:-

> 2. everything that can be conceived of  [Collins English Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

In this case, it means every imaginable feature has been included.

Comment: Hmm, the first definition at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kitchen+sink seems to contradict its second definition. So "kitchen sink" can be used to refer to the last item,  **and** it can also be used to refer to all the items before it?

Comment: @Pacerier, the kitchen sink being the last item on the list _means_ that every other possible item is already on it.

Answer (score 1):

The new CMS product has considered the furthest function that its user can imagine. Refer to 'Kitchen sink' as [the final item imaginable on any extensive list of usually disparate items](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kitchen-sink).

It sounds applicable in the context.

Comment: Speculation is OK as a comment, but not as an answer.